# How to concatenate negative integers into characters c language

Tags: c, concatenation, subtraction, negative-number

I have created a script to collect timestamps in sec and microsec. Then I am trying to calculate the difference of these values. The result is as expected as long as the integers are positive.

As a next step I convert the integers into strings and concatenate them with a dot in between. It is much easier in human readable format to be read by the user.

The problem appears when the integers are negative. First of all I can not figure it out how to print the negative sign when I convert the negative int into a string. (e.g. 3sec . -3microsec)

Second of all it could become even worse in case that both integers are negative and I have two negative signs. (e.g. -3sec . -3microsec)

So my question is, since I trying to subtract two integers that in reality are floats is there any other alternative that I could concatenate them into a float and then apply subtraction? (e.g. int 3sec int 3microsec concatenation to float 3.3sec)

I am a beginner in C language so I am not sure if this is possible, this is the reason that I have been through in all of this process (converting int to strings and then concatenation).

Sample of executable code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define TIME_CHAR 22
#define PROCESS_CHARACTERS 32

typedef struct rec {
  char time_1[TIME_CHAR];
  char time_2[TIME_CHAR];
  char time_3[TIME_CHAR];
  char process[PROCESS_CHARACTERS];
}RECORD;

char *u2s(long unsigned int number) {

  RECORD *ptr_record = malloc (sizeof(RECORD));

  if (ptr_record == NULL) {
    printf("Out of memory!\nExit!\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  const int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", number);
  assert(n > 0);
  char buf[n+1];
  snprintf(buf, n+1, "%lu", number);
  assert(buf[n] == '\0');
  memcpy(ptr_record->process, buf , sizeof buf);

  return ptr_record->process;

}

uint32_t ClockGetTime() {
  struct timespec ts;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
  return (int32_t)ts.tv_sec * 1000000LL + (int32_t)ts.tv_nsec / 1000LL;
}

void cleanup(RECORD** ptr_record) {
  free(*ptr_record);
  *ptr_record = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char *dot = ".";
  RECORD *ptr_record;

  ptr_record = malloc (sizeof(RECORD));

  if (ptr_record == NULL) {
    printf("Out of memory!\nExit!\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  /* Originate Time Stamps for time_1 */
  time_t time_1_sec = time(NULL);
  uint32_t client_1_sec = time_1_sec;
  uint32_t client_1_microsec = ClockGetTime();

  char *client_1_sec_string = u2s(client_1_sec);
  char *client_1_microsec_string = u2s(client_1_microsec);

  memset( ptr_record->time_1 , '\0' , sizeof ptr_record->time_1 );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_1 , client_1_sec_string , strlen(client_1_sec_string) );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_1 , dot , strlen(dot) );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_1 , client_1_microsec_string ,     strlen(client_1_microsec_string) );

  /* Originate Time Stamps for time_2 */
  time_t time_2_sec = time(NULL);
  uint32_t client_2_sec = time_2_sec;
  uint32_t client_2_microsec = ClockGetTime();

  char *client_2_sec_string = u2s(client_2_sec);
  char *client_2_microsec_string = u2s(client_2_microsec);

  memset( ptr_record->time_2 , '\0' , sizeof ptr_record->time_2 );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_2 , client_2_sec_string , strlen(client_2_sec_string) );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_2 , dot , strlen(dot) );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_2 , client_2_microsec_string , strlen(client_2_microsec_string) );

  printf("This is buffer time_2: %s\n",ptr_record->time_2);

  int32_t d_positive_sec = client_2_sec - client_1_sec;
  int32_t d_positive_microsec = client_2_microsec - client_1_microsec;

  printf("This is the positive difference in sec: %"PRId32"\n",d_positive_sec);
  printf("This is the positive difference in microsec: %"PRId32"\n",d_possitive_microsec);

  int32_t d_negative_sec = client_1_sec - client_2_sec;
  int32_t d_negative_microsec = client_1_microsec - client_2_microsec;

  printf("This is the negative difference in sec: %"PRId32"\n",d_negative_sec);
  printf("This is the negative difference in microsec: %"PRId32"\n",d_negative_microsec);

  char *n_sec_string = u2s(d_negative_sec);
  char *n_microsec_string = u2s(d_negative_microsec);

  memset( ptr_record->time_3 , '\0' , sizeof ptr_record->time_3 );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_3 , n_sec_string , strlen(n_sec_string) );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_3 , dot , strlen(dot) );
  strncat( ptr_record->time_3 , n_microsec_string , strlen(n_microsec_string) );

  printf("This is negative concatenated %s\n",ptr_record->time_3);

  cleanup(&ptr_record);

  return 0;

} /* End of main(){} */
```

Sample of output:

```
This is the positive difference in sec: 0
This is the positive difference in microsec: 37
This is the negative difference in sec: 0
This is the negative difference in microsec: -37
This is negative concatenated 0.18446744073709551579
```

It is easy to tell that after the concatenation we should expect to see (0.-37), the best possible result would be (-0.37).

Comment: 0s plus 37us would give 0.000037s not 0.37s!

Comment: This is absolutely true, what can I do to fix this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Switch to the smaller resolution when doing caclulations. When done, scale back to the unit needed.

Comment: In your case you can check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/ : this Write formatted output to sized buffer. You can also check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ for different format specifier.

Comment: @VishalGupta the links that you provide me are really useful. Thank you for your time and effort to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's method of getting time is flawed.  It retrieves the `second` and `microsecond` from 2 calls, yet time elapses between the 2 calls and the numbers of seconds could have incremented.  Instead, re-write `ClockGetTime()` to get both `sec` and `microsec`.

```
// time_t time_1_sec = time(NULL);
// uint32_t client_1_sec = time_1_sec;
// uint32_t client_1_microsec = ClockGetTime();
```

As suggested by @alk, covert to a common scale, then subtract

```
// int32_t d_positive_sec = client_2_sec - client_1_sec;
// int32_t d_positive_microsec = client_2_microsec - client_1_microsec;
// printf("This is the positive difference in sec: %"PRId32"\n",d_positive_sec);
// printf("This is the positive difference in microsec: %"PRId32"\n",     
//     d_possitive_microsec);

int64_t t1 = client_1_sec;
t1 = t1*1000000 /* microseconds per second */ + client_1_microsec;
int64_t t2 = client_2_sec;
t2 = t2*1000000 + client_2_microsec;
int64_t diff = t2 - t1;
int64_t diff_sec = diff/1000000;
int32_t diff_usec = diff%1000000;
if (diff_usec < 0) diff_usec = -diff_usec;

printf("Difference: %" PRId64 ".%06" PRId32 " sec\n", diff_sec, diff_usec);
```

Converting to `float` would typically not provide sufficient precision.  Converting to `double` would typically be just enough precision for 32-bit `int` and ~20-bit usec.  This is another approach.

```
double t1 = client_1_sec;
t1 = t1*1000000 /* microseconds per second */ + client_1_microsec;
double t2 = client_2_sec;
t2 = t2*1000000 + client_2_microsec;
double diff = t2 - t1;

printf("Difference: %0.6f sec\n", diff);
```

---

Overall, recommend instead using `int64_t` to store the seconds and nanoseconds from `clock_gettime()` and use that in the difference calculation.

```
int64_t ClockGetTime(void) {
  struct timespec ts;
  if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts)) Handle_Error();
  return ts.tv_sec * ((int64_t)1000000000) + ts.tv_nsec;
}
```

---

Minor note

`u2s` goes though a lot of work to carefully not overflow `buf` when constructing the string representation of a number.  Yet it happily does `memcpy(ptr_record->process, buf , sizeof buf)` without checking that `sizeof buf <= sizeof ptr_record->process`.

Comment: Perfect, it makes absolute sense. I should convert them in the same scale add seconds with the microseconds into 64 bits (8 bytes) to be able to fit the two 32 bit values. As a second step to make the calculation. Nice, thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: A small update on the answer. While I was adjusting your answer to my code I noticed a small detail. `if (diff_usec < 0) diff_usec = -diff_usec;` should be like this `if ((diff_sec < 0) || (diff_usec < 0)) diff_sec = -diff_sec;`. The reason is that we want to test if either the microseconds have a negative value or if the seconds have a negative value. In any case of those two we want the seconds to take the negative sign on the front. Again thank you for your time and effort I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can/should read all about printf format conversions at:

<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders>

which states:

the full syntax of a conversion parameter is:
**%[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type**
where [parameter] is a posix extension ... (see linked page for details)
```

Flags can be zero or more (in any order) of:

```
Character   Description
**+     always denote the sign '+' or '-' of a number (the default is to omit the sign for positive numbers). Only applicable to numeric types.**
space   prefixes non-negative signed numbers with a space
-   left-align the output of this placeholder (the default is to right-align the output).
#   Alternate form. For 'g' and 'G', trailing zeros are not removed. For 'f', 'F', 'e', 'E', 'g', 'G', the output always contains a decimal point. For 'o', 'x', and 'X', a 0, 0x, and 0X, respectively, is prepended to non-zero numbers.
0   use 0 instead of spaces to pad a field when the width option is specified. For example, printf("%2d", 3) results in " 3", while printf("%02d", 3) results in "03".
```

Width specifies a minimum number of characters to output, and is typically used to pad fixed-width fields in tabulated output, where the fields would otherwise be smaller, although it does not cause truncation of oversized fields. A leading zero in the width value is interpreted as the zero-padding flag mentioned above, and a negative value is treated as the positive value in conjunction with the left-alignment "-" flag also mentioned above.

Precision usually specifies a maximum limit on the output, depending on the particular formatting type. For floating point numeric types, it specifies the number of digits to the right of the decimal point that the output should be rounded. For the string type, it limits the number of characters that should be output, after which the string is truncated.

Length can be omitted or be any of:

```
Character   Description
hh  For integer types, causes printf to expect an int-sized integer argument which was promoted from a char.
h   For integer types, causes printf to expect an int-sized integer argument which was promoted from a short.
l   For integer types, causes printf to expect a long-sized integer argument.

For floating point types, causes printf to expect a double argument.
ll  For integer types, causes printf to expect a long long-sized integer argument.
L   For floating point types, causes printf to expect a long double argument.
z   For integer types, causes printf to expect a size_t-sized integer argument.
j   For integer types, causes printf to expect a intmax_t-sized integer argument.

so just include the '+' flag in the format conversion parameter and 
if the value is negative, then a '-' will be printed in the output
t   For integer types, causes printf to expect a ptrdiff_t-sized integer argument.
```

Comment: Perfect, I was not aware with all these details. I will read the linked that you provide me and try to adjust it on my script. Thank you for your time and effort.